# Pagination without page reload using JQuery/AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to paginate results from my select query in PHP using Previous and Next buttons. The problem is, I want to do it without reloading the page. Is it possible to do so? Also I have a problem when I filter the results. For example, I want to only see the active users. My problem with that is only the first page is filtered. Any solutions for that? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do. You can use AJAX and jQuery and just update parts of the page. Quick example

```
$.get(url,function(data,status){
    $('some-div').html(data);
})
```

As far as the filtering goes, you would probably have to re-filter it upon getting new data. It is most likely happening with your code because you are reloading the page and the filtering would go away, but without seeing code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks for this information. It will be important for future references

Comment: UPDATE: I found the solution on this link https://codepen.io/bastony/post/tablesortingtutorial-js